# Show the selected option with group label in <optgroup>

Tags: jquery, html, css, optgroup

I have the following code. I want when an option is selected then with `selected option` the `group label` should be shown how to achieve it ?

```
<select id='#grp_option'>
 <optgroup label="Group 1">
 <option>Option 1.1</option>
</optgroup> 
<optgroup label="Group 2">
 <option>Option 2.1</option>
 <option>Option 2.2</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Group 3" disabled>
 <option>Option 3.1</option>
 <option>Option 3.2</option>
 <option>Option 3.3</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

I tried in jquery & googled out but no solution i found. I tried script like
`onchange`

```
function showLabel(e){ 
 var selected = $('#grp_option :selected');
 var id = #grp_option;
 var cu_label = $(selected).val();
 var label=$(selected).parent().attr('label') + ' - ';
 var tlabel = label + cu_label; 
 //$(id).text(tlabel);
 console.log(tlabel);
}
```

In console.log i get Group 2 - Option 2.1. But i want to show this in `select input value`  Any body knows how to achieve it ?

Comment: Once you do `var selected = $('#grp_option :selected')`, you don't have to do `$(selected)` to access the jQuery properties. `selected.parent()` works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the values what ever you want to show. As below i have done.

```
<select id='grp_option'>
  <optgroup label="Group 1">
    <option value='Group 1 - Option 1.1'>Option 1.1</option>
  </optgroup> 
  <optgroup label="Group 2">
    <option value='Group 2 - Option 2.1'>Option 2.1</option>
    <option value='Group 2 - Option 2.2'>Option 2.2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Then just add this script. Here you go

```
$('#grp_option option').each(function () {
     $(this).data('txt', $(this).text());
});

$('#grp_option').change(function () {
 $('option', this).each(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).data('txt'));
 });

 $(this).find('option:selected').text($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value'));
});
```

Its done.

Answer (score 3):

You were close! Try this:

HTML

```
<label id="target" for="grp_option">Selected: </label>
<br/>
<select id="grp_option">
    <optgroup label="Group 1">
        <option>Option 1.1</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 2">
        <option>Option 2.1</option>
        <option>Option 2.2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 3" disabled>
        <option>Option 3.1</option>
        <option>Option 3.2</option>
        <option>Option 3.3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#grp_option').on('change', function () {
        showLabel();
    });

    // fire on page load
    $('#grp_option').change();
});

function showLabel() {
    var selected = $('#grp_option :selected');
    var item = selected.text();
    var group = selected.parent().attr('label');
    $('#target').text('Selected: ' + group + ' - ' + item);
}
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ojj0L7ht/

Comment: Okay good one but i want to show the value in the dropdown itself.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. The dropdown will always display the selected item. Are you wanting to change the dropdown text to something like `Group 1 - Option 1.1`?

Comment: Here's an example of changing the text of the currently selected option: http://jsfiddle.net/ojj0L7ht/1/
The problem (as you can see) is that the text isn't changed back when another option is selected. To do that, you'd have to store the items in an array on the JS side and then dynamically load them using jQuery.

Comment: Okay good one...some bug is there...but still i will try to fix it.

Comment: Cheers. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: Yes the actually its keep on changing the selected text...so if we can remove the previous selected text. Then its will be simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
function showLabel(e){ 
 var selected = $('#grp_option :selected');
 var id = '#grp_option';
 var cu_label = $(selected).val();
 var label=$(selected).parent().attr('label') + ' - ';
 var tlabel = label + cu_label; 
 //$(id).text(tlabel);
 console.log(tlabel);
}
```

And change the id of drop down `#grp_option` to `grp_option` like

```
<select id='grp_option'>
```

Also add the `value` attribute to all `options` like,

```
<option value="3.1">Option 3.1</option>
<option value="3.2">Option 3.2</option>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/oqsmz6bt/)

Comment: i am getting the value in console.log. But i need to show it in select input value.

Comment: If you try `$(id).text(tlabel);` then it will vanish your previously added options. So, you can make a clone of the same drop down or make a different input element to set the value.

Comment: i didn't get you..how to make the clone ??

Comment: Good idea...let me see how i can proceed.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only the text of a selected option into optgroup select try this:

```js
var text = $("select[name='selectName'] :selected").text();
console.log(text);
```